# Why doesn't my String check code work

Tags: java, string, swing, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a JFrame which checks to see if text placed in a JTextField are the same as the information in a .txt file.
Then if that's correct, it checks to see if the information in the JPasswordField match the information in the .txt file.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == button)
    {
        if(!username.getText().equals("") && passIsGood())
        {
            try
            {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("users.txt"));
                reader.useDelimiter("\t|\n");
                reader.nextLine();
                while(reader.hasNextLine())
                {
                    if(reader.next().equals(username.getText()))
                    {
                        //Username is correct, now checks for password:
                        System.out.println("Username passed");      
                        if(reader.next().equals(passToString()))
                        {
                            //Username & Password are correct
                            System.out.println("Password passed");
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if(!reader.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        wrongInfo();
                    } else
                    {
                        reader.nextLine();
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
                frame.dispose();
            } catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }
        } else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid Username and Password");
        }
    }
}

private static String passToString()
{
    String passString = new String(password.getPassword());
    return passString;
}
```

I get as far as the username passing, but I feel like the .equals(passToString()) may be causing the problem.
The text file looks like this:
Username Password
test thetest
test2 thetest3

Note that the spaces in between each field are tabs, hence my delimiter using ("\t|\n");

Comment: after each second field in the users.txt is a new line

Comment: Why you need to call reader.nextLine() in the top?

Comment: @sasankad The first line in my .txt file was for formatting, it said "Username password" as the first line to indicate how to write out the rest, and I wanted to ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Strings contained in your textfields may contain some unwanted characters. Use a character domain (all ascii values that are a symbol) to get rid of those. Try this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class readUsers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("users.txt"));
            reader.useDelimiter("\t|\n");

            String username = "username";
            String password = "password";

            for (int i = 0; i < username.length(); i++) {
                //replace possible unwanted characters
                if (username.charAt(i) < 33 || username.charAt(i) > 126)
                    username = username.replace(Character.toString(username.charAt(i)), "");
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < password.length(); j++) {
                //replace possible unwanted characters
                if (password.charAt(j) < 33 || password.charAt(j) > 126)
                    password = password.replace(Character.toString(password.charAt(j)), "");
            }

            while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
                String user = reader.next();
                String pass = reader.next();

                //if username equals the user in the textfile, check if password equals the pass in the file
                 if (user.equals(username)) {
                    System.out.println("username passed!");
                    if (pass.equals(password))
                        System.out.println("password passed!");
                }   
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My textfile looks like this: 
username    password
username2   password

P.S. This is my first StackOverFlow answer ever, correct me if I do anything wrong :)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I found a rather simpler solution though, turns out my problem was the username contained a seemingly unnoticeable \n in the beginning, so I simply used the String.trim(); method to fix it, thank you regardless!

Comment: I couldn't know which character was causing the problem though ;)